# Forcing VS to open DependentUpon files with Code Editor not Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've fiddled my .csproj file to force a generated state machine code file to be 'dependentupon' a control. It works ok, but the problem is that when I double click, it opens the Designer by default, instead of the code editor. (VS automatically adds the SubType 'Form')

Is there anyway to work around this default behaviour (as VS seems to be able to for .Designer.cs)?

(By the way, I know about the [VSCommands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf/) plugin, that doesn't alter the problem though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem with SubType is that in most cases background compiler will overwrite its value. What happens is that if you manually change SubType on files such as *.cs or *.vb the compiler will change it back to whatever it thinks is best.

I have tried to change the value programatically using VS SDK but there currently seems to be no way to stop compiler from changing it back.

[Here is more info from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984495%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> This property is read-write, but the compiler may overwrite the value. For example, the SubType of a Windows.Forms.Form item may be changed through automation to "Code", but the compiler will reset the SubType to "Form".

[and connect report closed as 'By Design'](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/283434/vs-2005-sp1-ide-changes-subtype-of-cs-file-when-loading-project)